# Actualizar un solo registro seleccionado con Tkinter y ,Psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, tkinter

Ya logre actualizar con (Psycopg2-Tkinter). Pero lo hace sobre todos los registros, como hago para que aplique solo para el registro seleccionado.

```
Button(self.edit_wind, text='Actualizar',
               command=lambda: self.edit_records(nombre=new_nombre.get(), salario=new_salario.get())).grid(row=4,
                                                                                                           column=2,
                                                                                                           sticky=W)
        self.edit_wind.mainloop()


    def edit_records(self, nombre, salario):

        query=("UPDATE empleado SET nombre=%s, salario=%s where id=%s")  


        parameters = (nombre, salario)
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.edit_wind.destroy()
        self.message['text'] = 'Empleado {} Actualizado Satisfactoriamente'.format(nombre)
        self.get_empleados()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = root()
    application = Empleado(window)
    window.mainloop()
    #tk.Button.quit()
```

> Si desean revisar todo el código, este es el [enlace](https://pastebin.com/E2vSRehE).
>
> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dentro de tu pregunta, estás considerando el hecho de que tienes comentado el **WHERE** de tu UPDATE?.

Comment: Si, es cierto porque de las tantas opciones que he intentado, lo hice aplicando el WHERE para lograr ejecutar la actualizacion de la fla. pero tampoco me funciono y lo deje como comentario (#). y creo que no lo toma al leer la query, consulta.

Comment: tienes un UPDATE sin WHERE

Comment: Si, necesita el where, ??? es parte de mi pregunta?

Comment: cuando editas, debes almacenar el id por lo menos en una variable, cuando el usuario oprima guardar actualizas en base al id

Comment: Ok, pero en codigo como aplicaria esa query, para lograr el update de la fila.?

Comment: `UPDATE empleado SET nombre=%s, salario=%s where id=%s`

Comment: Evaluare y te comento.

Comment: Devuelve este error      (return super(DictCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "=%"
LINE 1: UPDATE empleado SET nombre=%s, salario=%s where id=%s)